# Timer event is not triggering button click

Tags: c#, wpf, file, timer, copy

I'm trying transfer `Image file` for **each 3 seconds** from source to destination directory, when I click on the *"Start" button*. And *"Stop" button* is for stopping the file transfer.

***If I use the Start button for the third time, the event is not firing; so, the files are not transferring.***

The progress I've done is in the below:

1. Start --- File Transferring; Pressed STOP Button ***// It Works as well.***
2. Start --- File Transferring; Pressed STOP Button ***// It works as well.***
3. *Start ----- File is not transferring, `Event is not firing`* ***// It not works!***

### What I've done for solving the problem:

- I put a break-point in the Tick event and the tick event is not firing.
- I Checked that SourceFiles.Count is greater than the TransferCount *(SourceFiles.Count > TransferCount)*.
- I noticed that during the file transfer, if I click Stop button during a file transfer that particular file remains un-transferred.

How can i fix this? Thank you in advance.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace GridTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window3.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window3 : Window
    {
        DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        private static List<string> SourceFiles = new List<string>();
        private static readonly string SourceDir = @"C:\TestFiles\Images\";
        private static readonly string DestinationDir = @"C:\Files\Images\3_5x5\";
        private static int TransferCount = 0;
        public Window3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += Window3_Loaded;
        }
        void Window3_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
            dispatcherTimer.Tick += dt_Tick;
        }
        void dt_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (TransferCount < SourceFiles.Count)
            {
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(SourceFiles[TransferCount]);
                var destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(DestinationDir, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(SourceFiles[TransferCount], destFile,true);
                System.IO.File.Delete(SourceFiles[TransferCount]);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total Files: {0} Number of files transferred: {1}", SourceFiles.Count, TransferCount + 1));
                TransferCount += 1;
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total number of files transferred: {0}. Transfer Completed", TransferCount + 1));
                (sender as DispatcherTimer).Stop();
                (sender as DispatcherTimer).Tick -= dt_Tick;
            }
        }

        private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(DestinationDir))
            {
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationDir);
            }

            if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(SourceDir))
            {
                SourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDir).ToList();
            }
        }

        private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            dispatcherTimer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: After the call to Stop_Click how do you restart the timer?

Comment: @Steve: Do i have to restart the timer?

Comment: What's the version of the .NET runtime you're targeting?

Comment: @linguini, are you using VS2012+? Your code scenario is ideal for re-factoring using `async/await`.

Comment: @Noseratio: yes, i'm using VS2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call Stop, your timer event should not fire until you set IsEnabled property to true.
So I suggest to do a bit of refactoring

```
    void Window3_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LoadSourceFiles();
        StartTimer();
    }
    void StartTimer()
    {
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 3);
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += dt_Tick;
        dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled = true;
    }
    void LoadSourceFiles()
    {
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(DestinationDir))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(DestinationDir);
        }

        if (System.IO.Directory.Exists(SourceDir))
        {
            SourceFiles = Directory.GetFiles(SourceDir).ToList();
        }
    }
```

and call this method every time you press the Start button

```
    private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StartTimer();
    }

    private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled = false;
    }
```

I suggest also to reset the global variable that keeps track of the files transfered to zero when inside the Tick event you discover that every file has been transfered (or disable the Start button)

```
    ....
    else
    {
          Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total number of files transferred: {0}. Transfer Completed", TransferCount + 1));
          (sender as DispatcherTimer).Stop();
          (sender as DispatcherTimer).Tick -= dt_Tick;
          TransferCount = 0;
    }
```

Otherwise if you restart the timer in this situation it will stop immediately

Comment: :3-4 images files are transferred at a time, may i know why? Is it possible to transfer one by one? Thank you

Comment: You have an interval of 3 seconds, if copying a file takes more than 3 seconds it is possible that another timer event is added to the Dispatcher queue and you receive that event also in case of stop. You could try if this is the case incrementing the interval and check the results then

Comment: Interesting that First click 1 file transferred, 2nd tile click 2 files are transferred; 3rd Click, 3 files are transferred..4th Click 4 files are transferred.

Comment: Do you mean that if you click the Start just one file is copied and then the event doesn't fire again?

Comment: Sorry for my bad explanation. The vent works perfectly. Click 1st time on Start button:: 1 File is transferred. Clicked on Stop Button
Click 2nd time on Start button: 2 Files are transferred. Clicked on Stop Button
Click 3rd time on Start button: 3 Files are transferred. Clicked on Stop Button
etc....

Comment: That's because the variable that keeps the index of the files to be transfered is printed like it was the count of files transfered in a single tick event. The message should be something like `"Transfered the " + TransferCount.ToString() + " file of " + SourceFiles.Count.ToString() + " to be transfered"`

Comment: Great! I didn't think about the variable. I guess, this is how it should work, we can't change more then this? Correct me if i'm wrong.

Comment: No, unless totally changing the approach. The answer from Noseratio is an example (cannot comment on that because I haven't used async/await), or using a separate Thread. But it all depend on the real complexity of your work.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48142/discussion-between-linguini-and-steve)

Answer (score 2):

Not really an answer, but here's a re-factored version which doesn't use timer. Instead, it uses `TaskEx.Delay` and `async/await`, untested (targeting .NET 4.0 with vs2012+ and [`Microsoft.Bcl.Async`](http://www.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.bcl.async)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GridTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Window3.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Window3 : Window
    {
        private static List<string> SourceFiles = new List<string>();
        private static readonly string SourceDir = @"C:\TestFiles\Images\";
        private static readonly string DestinationDir = @"C:\Files\Images\3_5x5\";
        public Window3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.Loaded += Window3_Loaded;
        }
        void Window3_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        async Task DoWorkAsync(CancellationToken token)
        {
            int transferCount;
            for (transferCount = 0; transferCount < SourceFiles.Count; transferCount++)
            {
                token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                var fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(SourceFiles[transferCount]);
                var destFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(DestinationDir, fileName);
                System.IO.File.Copy(SourceFiles[transferCount], destFile, true);
                System.IO.File.Delete(SourceFiles[transferCount]);
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total Files: {0} Number of files transferred: {1}", SourceFiles.Count, transferCount + 1));
                transferCount += 1;

                await TaskEx.Delay(3000, token); // 3s delay
            }
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Total number of files transferred: {0}. Transfer Completed", transferCount + 1));
        }

        CancellationTokenSource _cts;
        Task _task;

        private void Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_cts != null)
                _cts.Cancel();
            _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            _task = TaskEx.Run(() => DoWorkAsync(_cts.Token), _cts.Token);
        }

        private void Stop_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_cts != null)
                _cts.Cancel();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. I'll try this approach & it'll be useful for me to understand this concept.

Answer (score 1):

You never call [Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on the DispatchTimer.

Add this to the Window3_Loaded method:

```
dispatcherTimer.Start();
```

Comment: I  have added `dispatcherTimer.Start();`still i have the same problem. In third click the tick event is not firing.